# ajax sem permissao de consulta

Tags: ajax, wcf, webmethods

tenho um webservice em wcf no link http://food-fast-com.web27.redehost.net/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo/2, consigo consumi-lo sem problema no meu iis local com o ajax:

Consulta Usuario

```
      <div><table id="datagrid"></table></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConsUsuario(){
        var value = $("#codUser").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        //url: "ServiceRestPub/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo/" + value,
        url: "http://food-fast-com.web27.redehost.net/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo/" + value,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
          var tabela = $("#datagrid");
                            var rows = "";
                            tabela.find("tbody td").remove();

                                rows += "<tr>";
                                rows += " <td>" + result.ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult.Codigo + "</td>";
                                rows += " <td>" + result.ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult.Login + "</td>";
                                rows += " <td>" + result.ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult.Nome+ "</td>";
                                rows += " <td> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>";
                                rows += "</tr>";

                tabela.html('<tbody>' + rows + '</tbody>');
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

Porem, ao consumir o do link postado acima tenho o seguinte retorno: 
**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost'**. 
Tentei colocar o seguinte codigo no WebConfig:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" />-
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

No meu iis local funciona, porem quando faco o upload para meu servidor da o seguinte erro:

```
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

Falei com o pessoal do suporte ele disse que é padrão não permitir esse tipo de implementação no webconfig.

Como faço para consumir com ajax esse webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remova o ContentType da requisição e adicione:

```
 crossDomain: true,
 dataType: 'jsonp',
```

Segue:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://food-fast-com.web27.redehost.net/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo/" + value,
   crossDomain: true,
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function (result) { ... },
   error: function(data){ ... }
```

> If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same
>   domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for
>   example, server-side redirection to another domain

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Obrigado Aline, porem não queria usar jsonp devido as suas limitações com POST e segurança, queria colocar as permissoes no servidor (CORS) e acessar é possivel?

Comment: testando da maneira que você disse apresenta o erro Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token, debugando vi que ele esta trazendo o valor mas é como não conseguisse interpreta-lo

Comment: Aline, na verdade o erro foi meu, meu site vai ficar hospedado no mesmo dominio do webservice então vai funcionar blz, ja testei, o problema era eu querendo que ele funcionasse do localhost, ai num vai. kkk, obrigado mais uma vez por sua atenção!